# package org.hibernate.annotations does not exist

Tags: entity, jhipster

I have generated Jhipster Application which was working fine & was building successfully but after generating the entities it is not building & showing this error in file

which is /src/main/java/com/foodnet/mandi/domain/Buyer.java

Actually i generated the buyer entity

Comment: Please, provide you code.

Comment: i found out its solution by adding the dependency of org.hibernate.annotaions in pom.xml file

Comment: If you have solution, could you add new answer and mark you question as resolved?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
I put a dependency in pom.xml file

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
  <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
</dependency>
```

& My problem was solved

Comment: Is this jar file will be compatible with Hibernate-core-5.2.17-Final? or any new version of Jar file can you suggest which will support for org.hibernate.annotations package?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have hibernate jar included in classpath. Which build tool are you using?

Comment: i am using maven build tool

Comment: how to find what is my classpath